# How do I use rgba in scss as a css variable?

Tags: css, sass

I currently have the following using dart sass...

```
color: rgba(144, 202, 249, 0.5);
```

I would like to make it a css variable so I tried this...

```
--background-color: rgba(144, 202, 249, 0.5);
...
background-color: --background-color;
```

But I get

```
Error: expected "{".
  ╷
1 │ --background-color: rgba(144, 202, 249, 0.5);
```

I also tried...

```
--background-color: 144, 202, 249;
--opacity: 0.5;
...
background-color: rgba(var(--background-color), var(--opacity));
```

But still no dice

```
Error: expected "{".
  ╷
1 │ --background-color: 144, 202, 249;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're defining your variable properly in the appropriate scope. Your initial color syntax is correct. Also be sure to reference the color with `var(--name)` (missing in your first code snippet).

```css
.root {
  --background-color: rgba(144, 202, 249, 0.5);
}

.example {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="root"><div class="example" /></div>
```

Comment: Can I still override it outside of the shadowdom? (Since it is root)

Comment: I've updated to not use the `:root` pseudo element. It looks like you can - https://codepen.io/apexskier/pen/dyYPgLP